# Configure logging in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have a question on how to configure my python logger. Below you can see my current set up of the logger. (http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html)

```
logger = logging.getLogger("someName")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.FileHandler("./log/log.out", "w")
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

frm = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s','H:%M:%S')
fh.setFormatter(frm)
ch.setFormatter(frm)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

Is there a way to configure the logger in such a way that it also writes error messages like the one below:

```
print a
>>> NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your code in a `try:`, `except Exception:` block and call `logger.exception()`:

```
try:
    print a
except Exception:
    logger.exception('Oops, something went wrong')
```

You could add a `raise` statement to that to re-raise the caught exception.

Demo:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig()
>>> logger = logging.getLogger()
>>> def foo():
...     print a
... 
>>> def bar(i=0):
...     if i < 3:
...         bar(i + 1)
...     else:
...         foo()
... 
>>> def baz():
...     try:
...         bar()
...     except Exception:
...        logger.exception('Oops, something went wrong')
... 
>>> def spam(): baz()
... 
>>> spam()
ERROR:root:Oops, something went wrong
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in baz
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in bar
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in bar
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in bar
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in bar
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

The traceback was logged by the `logging` module, not by my interactive Python session.

The traceback leads from the `try` block to the exception; the `spam()` function is the above example is not included.

Comment: I think this is not what I want, since I dont get a hint were the bug really is. In my orignial code the error message in the console is to long, to see it entirely, so I think this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @swot: The full traceback is logged to your logfile. My sample exception is rather short, what makes you think this is a truncated traceback?

Comment: Actually, if I have `def somefunction(): print a` I didnt get the full traceback in my log file. Any suggestions?

Comment: @swot: Where did you catch the exception? At the entry point of your program or inside `somefunction()`?

Comment: `create logger  </br> somefuntion()  </br> try:somefunction  </br> except Exception:  </br> logger.exception("oops)` This is the way I set it up. Does this help?

Comment: @swot: Did you mean `def somefunction()`, then `try: somefunction()`, `except ....`? Because it looks as if you are not calling the function in the correct location.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. Sry, I was to busy trying to make linebreaks. ;)

Comment: @swot: expanded my sample a little; the full traceback is still included from the point of the `try` block.

Comment: Ok, I had a `if __name__ == 'main'`statement bevor the `try`statement. Deleting the `if` statement has done the job.